# Is there a way to have my blit repeat itself after making it's first iteration?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, iteration, new-operator

It would be great if anyone with a basic understanding of pygames could help me out with the issue I am currently facing. It should not be too difficult for you absolute gods out there.

I am having trouble with my code as it stand right now.

I am attempting to make a simple game where the program displays a random letter and the user has to enter in that letter before it reaches the bottom of the page.

I have the code displaying the random letter in a random column, however, once the letter reaches the bottom, I only have the program print "end" and then quit the program.

I can not comprehend how to further develop the code. Here is the code as it stands right now:

```
import os                                                           # 
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (1335,330)           # sets the coordinates so that the window pops up in the lower right side of the screen (1600x900 screen)

import pygame                                                       # pygame is the platform im using
import random                                                       # random needs to be imported for the random letters and columns
pygame.init()                                                       # initializes pygame

win = pygame.display.set_mode((260, 527))                           # size of the window ,screenwidth = 260, screenheight = 527

pygame.display.set_caption("Daveypoo is King")                      # title of the window

clock = pygame.time.Clock()                                         # used for frame rate

bg = pygame.image.load('phone3cropped.jpg')                         # background picture upload

qp = pygame.image.load('q.png')                                     # uploads pictures of the letters (use paint, 50x50 pixels, black, 1 pixel outline, font = 36)
wp = pygame.image.load('w.png')                                     # ^
ep = pygame.image.load('e.png')                                     # ^
ap = pygame.image.load('a.png')                                     # ^
sp = pygame.image.load('s.png')                                     # ^
dp = pygame.image.load('d.png')                                     # ^
jp = pygame.image.load('j.png')                                     # ^
kp = pygame.image.load('k.png')                                     # ^
lp = pygame.image.load('l.png')                                     # ^

letterlist = [qp,wp,ep,ap,sp,dp,jp,kp,lp]                           # creates a list of letter images
randletter = random.choice(letterlist)                              # randomizes the list of images^

class player():                                                     # creates letter instance
    def __init__(self, x,y,width,height,end):                       # initializes the list
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height 
        self.path = [self.y, 415]                                   # creates the path that the letters will travel
        self.vel = 1                                                # this is where the velocity of the letters is set                                
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 50, 50)                      # creates the hitbox for the letter pictures (no need to change for now -- 50x50 is good)

    def move(self, win):                                            # creates the movement for the letters
        if self.vel > 0:                                            
            if self.y + self.vel < self.path[1] :                   # if the bottom of the letter is less than the end, then:
                self.y += self.vel                                  # keep going
            else:                                                   # if not:
                self.vel = 0                                        # stop moving
        else:                                                       # if the bottom of the letter is at the end, then
            print('end')
            quit()
            #redrawGameWindow()
                                                                    # this is where the action to make a new letter has to go


class greenzone(object):                                            # creates the zone (greenzone) where the player should get the letter in
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):                            # initializes it
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hitbox = (16, 342, 228, 66)                            # first two letters are top left (x,y) coordinate of the zone, next is width, next is height

    # def hit(self):
        # print('hit')

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))                                             # diplays the background image, coordinates of top left 
    win.blit(randletter, pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (letters.x, letters.y, letters.width, letters.height))) # displays the letters going down the page (letters.x, letters.y, letters.width, letters.height)
    # win.blit(randletter, pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (letters.x, letters.y, letters.width, letters.height)))
    letters.move(win)                                              # calls upon the movement of the letters -- makes them move
    # for letter in letters:
        # letter.draw(win)

    #pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (16, 342, 228, 66), 2)        # this shows the hitbox of the greenzone if needed
    pygame.display.update()                                         # idk what this does -- but it is needed

### mainloop
abc_list = [27,106,185]                                             # this is the list of the starting positions of the letters (top left)
rand = random.choice(abc_list)                                      # takes a random starting position of the letters 
letters = player(rand,56,50,50,415)                                 # instances the letters to start 
#letters = []                                                        # apparently creates a list of the the letters -- used to initialize and create new letters 
target = greenzone(18,343,228,67)                                   # sets the hitbox of the greenzone 

run = True
while run:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
            exit()

    # for letter in letters:
        # if letter.x < 500 and letter.x > 0:
            # letter.x += letter.vel
        # else:
            # letters.pop(letters.index(letter))

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_q] and randletter == qp:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and randletter == wp:            
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_e] and randletter == ep:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and randletter == ap:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and randletter == sp:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and randletter == dp:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_j] and randletter == jp:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_k] and randletter == kp:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    if keys[pygame.K_l] and randletter == lp:
        if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
        else:
            print('fail')

    redrawGameWindow()


pygame.quit()
```

I know this is a lot of code, I tried adding as many notes to it as possible in order to help anyone reading this understand my mindset with it.

Any and all help with this would be great. I know I am doing a lot wrong-- I only just started this a couple of days ago. Thanks for any input, appreciate it a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on additional information you provided:

> My main/overall problem that I am facing is that once the letter does
> hit the bottom, I want it to re-do the "iteration" of making a new
> random letter in a new column, and keep on repeating. Eventually, I
> want the program to only allow 5 "lives", and if they mess up more
> than 5 times, they either get the option to restart or quit the
> program.
>
> Along with that, my future aspirations for this code is to allow the user to select the speed and letter combinations that appear on
> the screen. But I personally believe that I would be able to code that
> once I have the overall code repeat itself (like I just described
> above)

I had to move the collision detection algorithm out of the keypress section. I also cleaned up the code to separate each section into its own function. I'm not too familiar with classes yet, so I didn't know what todo with target = greenzone(..) - also likely why I use global quite a bit

update(), init(), main() are straightforward. dropLetter() is the function you were looking for. in updateInput(), randLetterIndex is used to more efficiently check if the pressed key is what you need, I'm still in shock Python doesn't have a switch() statement, so this is what I came up with to get around that. checkCollision() - I tried to keep it as you had it as I'm unsure exactly what you plan for this game in the future. I did add a lot to the else statement, including moving the quit() statement to here

```
import os                                                           # 
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_WINDOW_POS'] = "%d,%d" % (1335,330)           # sets the coordinates so that the window pops up in the lower right side of the screen (1600x900 screen)

import pygame                                                       # pygame is the platform im using
import random                                                       # random needs to be imported for the random letters and columns
pygame.init()                                                       # initializes pygame

win = pygame.display.set_mode((260, 527))                           # size of the window ,screenwidth = 260, screenheight = 527

pygame.display.set_caption("Daveypoo is King")                      # title of the window

clock = pygame.time.Clock()                                         # used for frame rate

bg = pygame.image.load('phone3cropped.jpg')                         # background picture upload

qp = pygame.image.load('q.png')                                     # uploads pictures of the letters (use paint, 50x50 pixels, black, 1 pixel outline, font = 36)
wp = pygame.image.load('w.png')                                     # ^
ep = pygame.image.load('e.png')                                     # ^
ap = pygame.image.load('a.png')                                     # ^
sp = pygame.image.load('s.png')                                     # ^
dp = pygame.image.load('d.png')                                     # ^
jp = pygame.image.load('j.png')                                     # ^
kp = pygame.image.load('k.png')                                     # ^
lp = pygame.image.load('l.png')                                     # ^

letterlist = [qp,wp,ep,ap,sp,dp,jp,kp,lp]                           # creates a list of letter images
pygameKeyList = [pygame.K_q, pygame.K_w, pygame.K_e, pygame.K_a, pygame.K_s, pygame.K_d, pygame.K_j, pygame.K_k, pygame.K_l]
random.seed()                                                  # seed the RNG
abc_list = [27,106,185]                                             # this is the list of the starting positions of the letters (top left)
lives = 5                                                      # 5 lives to start
userPressingKey = False                                        # if user is currenlty pressing the key of the currently chosen letter
run = False

class player():                                                     # creates letter instance
    def __init__(self, x,y,width,height,end):                       # initializes the list
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height 
        self.path = [self.y, 415]                                   # creates the path that the letters will travel
        self.vel = 1                                                # this is where the velocity of the letters is set                                
        self.hitbox = (self.x, self.y, 50, 50)                      # creates the hitbox for the letter pictures (no need to change for now -- 50x50 is good)

    def move(self, win):                                            # creates the movement for the letters
        if self.vel > 0:                                            
            if self.y + self.vel < self.path[1] :                   # if the bottom of the letter is less than the end, then:
                self.y += self.vel                                  # keep going
            else:                                                   # if not:
                self.vel = 0                                        # stop moving
#        else:                                                       # if the bottom of the letter is at the end, then
#            print('end')
#            quit()
            #redrawGameWindow()
                                                                    # this is where the action to make a new letter has to go


class greenzone(object):                                            # creates the zone (greenzone) where the player should get the letter in
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height):                            # initializes it
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.hitbox = (16, 342, 228, 66)                            # first two letters are top left (x,y) coordinate of the zone, next is width, next is height

    # def hit(self):
        # print('hit')

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))                                             # diplays the background image, coordinates of top left 
    win.blit(letterlist[randLetterIndex], pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (letters.x, letters.y, letters.width, letters.height))) # displays the letters going down the page (letters.x, letters.y, letters.width, letters.height)
    # win.blit(randletter, pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 255, 255), (letters.x, letters.y, letters.width, letters.height)))
    letters.move(win)                                              # calls upon the movement of the letters -- makes them move
    # for letter in letters:
        # letter.draw(win)

    #pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (16, 342, 228, 66), 2)        # this shows the hitbox of the greenzone if needed
    pygame.display.update()                                         # idk what this does -- but it is needed

def dropLetter():
    #global randletter
    global letters, rand, randLetterIndex
    randLetterIndex = random.randrange(0,len(letterlist))
#    randletter = letterlist[randLetterIndex]                              # randomizes the list of images^
    rand = random.choice(abc_list)                                      # takes a random starting position of the letters 
    letters = player(rand,56,50,50,415)                                 # instances the letters to start 
    #letters = []                                                        # apparently creates a list of the the letters -- used to initialize and create new letters 

def checkCollision():
    global run, lives
    if letters.y < target.hitbox[1] + target.hitbox[3]:    
        if userPressingKey:
            if letters.y + letters.height > target.hitbox[1]:            
                print('hit')
            else:
                print('fail')
    else:
        print('fail hard')
        lives -= 1
        print("lives:",lives)
        if(lives <= 0):
            print('end')
            run = False
            quit()
        dropLetter()

def updateInput():
    global userPressingKey

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if(keys[pygameKeyList[randLetterIndex]]):
        userPressingKey = True
    else:
        userPressingKey = False


    # if keys[pygame.K_q] and randletter == qp:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_w] and randletter == wp:            
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_e] and randletter == ep:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_a] and randletter == ap:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_s] and randletter == sp:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_d] and randletter == dp:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_j] and randletter == jp:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_k] and randletter == kp:
    #     checkCollision()

    # if keys[pygame.K_l] and randletter == lp:
    #     checkCollision()

    # for letter in letters:
        # if letter.x < 500 and letter.x > 0:
            # letter.x += letter.vel
        # else:
            # letters.pop(letters.index(letter))


def update():
    updateInput()
    checkCollision()

def init():
    dropLetter()

def main():
    global run
    init()

    ### mainloop
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False
                exit()
        update()
        redrawGameWindow()
        clock.tick(144)


target = greenzone(18,343,228,67)                                   # sets the hitbox of the greenzone 
main()
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: My man I just want to say thank you so much for taking time out of your day to help me. I had a lot of fun with it so far, and I will continue to. It took me so long as it stood, you just helped me out big time. It means a lot to me for you to do this. Youre an absolute beast.